# Convert the MD5 output into 32 bit integer in Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have tried the following in Redshift

```
SELECT STRTOL(MD5('345793260804895811'), 10);
```

but I got the following `DBCException`:

> SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: The input cf82576a6dbf9ff63cf9828f990f0673 is not valid to be converted to base 10
>
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: PSQLException: ERROR: The input cf82576a6dbf9ff63cf9828f990f0673 is not valid to be converted to base 10

How may I get this done in Redshift?

Comment: MD5 function does not return numeric value. It's char(32) value and cannot be converted to numeric. You need other function to return bigint hash (Redshift doesn't have function of that kind built in)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have 2 problems:

- First, you need to specify the conversion as being base 16
- Second, an MD5 string will massively overflow a 64 bit `BIGINT` value

This works nicely

```
SELECT STRTOL(LEFT(MD5('345793260804895811'),15), 16);
```

Shortens the MD5 hex value to 15 leftmost characters and convert to a `BIGINT` using base 16.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this to store MD5 in two BIGINT fields instead of CHAR(32) - 2x space saving!

```
select 
    convert(bigint,
        strtol(substring(hash,1,8),16) * 4294967296.0 +
        strtol(substring(hash,9,8),16) - 9223372036854775807
    ) as hash_part1
    ,convert(bigint,
        strtol(substring(hash,17,8),16) * 4294967296.0 +
        strtol(substring(hash,25,8),16) - 9223372036854775807
    ) as hash_part2
```

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The result of MD5 is 128 bit long([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5)), you can not fit it into a 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with converting on base 16 instead of 10:

```
SELECT STRTOL(MD5('cf82576a6dbf9ff63cf9828f990f0673'), 16);
```